# HTTP post method did not get hit by breakpoint in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I try to validate the user message by using helperclass but its does not hit the httpPost method ,
In controller i have written below codings

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ItineraryItem data)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In model, i have defined the class ItineraryItem

```
 public class ItineraryItem
{
    public DateTime? When { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
}
```

In view page

```
<div class="editor" >
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.When)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.When)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.When)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Duration)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```